# Formulas behind Excel reports with SQL+

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, report

First of all, I know basic SQL and use SQL+ 8 on daily basis.

Question: I have some report about people's salary at work. There is some incorrect data in it I suppose. My company uses Oracle database.

Is it possible using SQL+ to see formulas behind that report? I mean to see how is salary calculated in each column or cell?

Thanks in advance, 
MP.

Comment: Assuming Excel is querying the database, you might be able to see the SQL it's running in the performance views. You won't be able to see anything Excel is doing with the data pulled from the database though. Why aren't you just looking at the workbook to see what it's doing and what formulas are used in the cells?

Comment: Out of interest, what is `SQL+ 8`?

Comment: I get the report right in excel without formulas in cells. I wanted to know if i could look up the"scheme" in sql. Ive acces to some tables about that report but there are only values. Is it possivle to see how sql calculate that values?

Comment: William i meant Sql*Plus 8.0;)